# how to set tabs on carousel bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have carousel with 1 image and under that by bootstrap4, I have tabs

my question is : 
how to set tabs fix on the carousel. 
No matter how hard I try, these two fall under each other .

see mycarousel : 
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG923.png)

and see my goal :

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j93aY.jpg)

look . Exactly the tabs are on the image .

my code :

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #mycarousel {
    height: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

.search {
  color: #656565;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item ">
      <img src="assets/img/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="assets/img/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <!--            <div class="carousel-item">-->
    <!--                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">-->
    <!--            </div>-->
  </div>
</div>

<section class="search py-4">
  <div class="container bg-dark">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav>
          <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">هتل داخلی</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">هتل خارجی</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
            <form>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">مقصد</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goal" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">مقصد2</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goal2">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">مقصد3</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goal3">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">مقصد 4</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goal4">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-sm-12">Submit</button>
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thanks for guiding me on how to put tabs on the carousel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this :

```css
#mycarousel {
    height: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.search {
  color: #656565;
  position: absolute;
    top: 40vh;
    left: 5vw;
    width:90vw
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #mycarousel {
    height: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.search {
  color: #656565;
  position: absolute;
    top: 40vh;
    left: 20vw;
    width:60vw
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item ">
      <img src="assets/img/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="assets/img/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <!--            <div class="carousel-item">-->
    <!--                <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">-->
    <!--            </div>-->
  </div>
</div>

<section class="search py-4">
  <div class="container bg-dark">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav>
          <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">هتل داخلی</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">هتل خارجی</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
            <form>
              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">مقصد</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goal" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">مقصد2</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goal2">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">مقصد3</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goal3">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-12">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">مقصد 4</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="goal4">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-sm-12">Submit</button>
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```